# Is this site limited to the 66 books of "the" Bible?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What texts are open for examination?](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/what-texts-are-open-for-examination)

Questions about the scope of this site:

1. Is it limited to the 66 books of the Protestant Bible?
2. Or does it include the OT Apocrypha, as sometimes used in Roman Catholic Bibles?
3. Does it include works used by other groups that consider themselves Christian and that consider those works divinely inspired, e.g. The Book of Mormon?

Comment: good question - but it has been asked before...

Comment: @JackDouglas: OK, thanks Jack. I missed that!