# Let's save our tags!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, challenge

It's been too long since I last proposed a [challenge](/questions/tagged/challenge)!  In the past [year](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/badges/13/yearling?userid=68), we've covered lots of ground, but there are still some books that we've only asked one question of.  Since these tags will [automatically disappear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127700/1438) unless we ask a second question, the challenge this week (from today until October 12 or so) is to save our singleton book tags.

Just to be clear, we don't need to save tags that probably will never apply to another question.  If you want to save those, go for it, but the challenge is to save these tags:

- [1-chronicles](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/1-chronicles)—Jon Ericson added a tag to a [question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/1434/68) that already existed
- [esther](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esther)—[Saved by Gone Quiet](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/2512/68)
- [jude](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jude)—[Saved by Frank Luke](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/2532/68)
- [malachi](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/malachi)—[Saved by Jon Ericson](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/2556/68)
- [2-peter](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2-peter)—[Saved by Soldarnal](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/2515/68)
- [1-thessalonians](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/1-thessalonians)—[Soldarnal noticed this tag was predestined for salvation](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/posts/348/revisions)
- [titus](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/titus)—[Saved by Soldarnal](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/2502/68)
- [zephaniah](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zephaniah)—[Saved by Steve Taylor](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/26447/2215)

And [possibly](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4/68):

- [dead-sea-scrolls](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dead-sea-scrolls)
- [josephus](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/josephus)—[Saved by Jon Ericson](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/2735/68)
- [gospel-of-thomas](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gospel-of-thomas)
- [tobit](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tobit)—[Saved by Jon Ericson](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/2667/68)
- [q-document](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/q-document)

---

I'm sure that there are a number of books that have *no* questions asked of them (I'm looking at you, minor prophets), but for the moment we don't have to worry about them.  But if you *do* ask a question that adds to this list, let us know.

As a reward for saving a tag, your name will be memorialized in this post for as long as we're online!

Comment: Oh, this is so nice! I like the concept of this -- what a great way to keep the site continuously valuable and constantly improving! :)

Comment: Related feature request on MSO: [Do not expire single use tags on Beta sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153357/do-not-expire-single-use-tags-on-beta-sites)

Comment: Should the gospel of Thomas tag even be saved given the agreed upon texts of the site?

Comment: Aslo related feature request on MSE: "[Do not expire single-use tags that have a tag wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127700/203418)" - and tagged [status-completed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/status-completed/info). :)