# On Posting a Possible Duplicate

Tags: discussion, specific-question, questions, asking-questions, exact-duplicates

I have already asked a [question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/100054) on a related site, concerning a possible inter-textual connection between two passages of *Daniel* (5:30-6:2 and 9:25-26), inquiring whether Jewish sages, specifically, have ever commented on the subject, and which remained unanswered, despite having been put up for bounty. I would like to ask a similar question on this site, but relating to [patristic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_Fathers) and/or scholarly commentaries on the same topic; however, I am unsure as to whether I would be allowed to do so, or whether it would constitute a breech of site policy concerning duplicates, which is why I am using this opportunity, and asking the community to weigh in on my dilemma.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see any problem with this. Questions across different sites are not usually considered duplicates as long as they are tailored to ask something specific tailored to the subject matter/expertise of each site.

The only really issue here is whether the question you want to ask is really better aimed at this site (is your goal reviewing the actual textual analysis, including academic or other contemporary hermeneutics, whether that be sourced from commentary or wherever?) or at [Christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com) (is your goal to review patristic history, traditions, etc.?). It's even possible you want to follow leads in both directions, in which case I would encourage asking specific questions on both sites tailored to the site scope of each.

Comment: I am interested in finding out whether some ancient Father(s) and/or reputable scholar(s) have ever linked the two passages; i.e., objective presentation of historical hermeneutic data, rather than subjective interpretations of individual users.

Comment: If I understand your second paragraph correctly, you are directing questions about patristic traditions to Chritianity.SE. But history of interpretation is on-topic ([+8/-0](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3490/21321)), so asking specifically about the understanding of patristic commentary should therefore be on-topic even with regard to traditions as long as they are asked with regard to a specific biblical passage