# How can the biblical topics close reason be improved/clarified?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

In the [Biblical Hermeneutics SE](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/) one of the VTC reasons has the following text

> Questions about biblical topics but without a specific Bible passage
> are off-topic as hermeneutical methods cannot be applied when no text
> is referenced.

This often misleads users who think that if a question doesn't include a specific Bible passage, then it's worth closing. That is not true and the [help center](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) explains it well

> Questions that do not arise from a Biblical text are off-topic unless
> they are about hermeneutical approaches. Not sure? You can find much
> more detail and all the nuances on our meta site.

Up to this point we've not been able to find a better word choice to convey this meaning.

How can the VTC message be written in a way that doesn't confuse users?

P.S. with this question I'm leveraging the power of different communities in helping each others too... it's not the first time (this question in [User Experience SE](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/132154/117492) helped this one in [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345098/364217)).

Comment: Those two messages are about different problems, the second isn't an explanation of the first.

Comment: @curiousdannii I know, the second one shows something else to be possible.

Comment: related: [reformulate the specific bible passage close reason](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3502/can-we-reformulate-the-specific-bible-passage-close-reason)

Answer (score 2):

Agreed with observations by others that there is significant overlap between the first two existing reasons:

> Questions about biblical topics but without a specific Bible passage are off-topic as hermeneutical methods cannot be applied when no text is referenced.

> Questions including a biblical text but that are not seeking an answer about ① the history of that biblical text itself or ② the meaning of that biblical text either in context or through a process of arriving at a particular interpretation of it are off-topic.

Also agreed with dannii's suggestion of merging these two and reusing the other. I'd tweak his and go with something like:

> Questions about **biblical text interpretation** are off-topic which: A) primarily seek current-day application of texts, or B) do not *arise from a specific text* in its own contemporary context.

> Questions about **biblical or theological topics** are off-topic if they are not seeking an answer about interpretation or the manuscript history of a [specific biblical passage](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/what-texts-are-open-for-examination), unless it's a question about the field of hermeneutics (*hermeneutical approaches*).

For the first one, I think it's helpful to have some aspect of 'history' - and for me this hones in on either the *manuscript history* or the [*interpretative history*](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3488/are-history-of-interpretation-questions-on-topic) of a text.

This second one could use some refining, I think - it would be good to have clearer boundaries around what it means for a question to arise from a text, as [I wrote on separately](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3734/what-does-it-mean-for-a-question-to-arise-from-a-biblical-text) a few weeks ago (but have not had time to follow up on since). It's difficult to be broad enough to allow well-intentioned questions and yet tight enough to restrict questions that are shoe-horned into a text.

Comment: The problem I have with my first proposed reason is that it could be used to close a question asking about the interpretative history of a passage.

Comment: Do you mean "how has this passage been understood through the ages?" I don't see how your revised first close reason would apply to that.

Comment: My concern with your first close reason is that it seems a little self-contradictory. A question can't be about **biblical text** interpretation if it's not about a biblical text. For your second close reason, is it really necessary to mention the field of hermeneutics? Would people really think of it as a biblical or theological topic? (I know some people think hermeneutical approach questions have been wrongfully closed, but I really haven't ever seen evidence of it being widespread. I think it's a non-issue.)

Comment: I do like that your second proposal includes manuscript history (textual criticism etc). That could be helpful to include. I'll keep thinking about how I might revise my proposal, to bring it closer to yours etc.

Answer (score 1):

There's definitely scope for changing the close reasons. Because actually we have two close reasons for the one single problem:

> Questions about biblical topics but without a specific Bible passage are off-topic as hermeneutical methods cannot be applied when no text is referenced.

> Questions including a biblical text but that are not seeking an answer about ① the history of that biblical text itself or ② the meaning of that biblical text either in context or through a process of arriving at a particular interpretation of it are off-topic.

These are both about Biblical or theological questions that do not primarily concern the exegesis of a passage. But we have two reasons because of the number of questions posted to this site which do not mention a passage at all, and it's much easier to explain what's wrong with a question if you can say "You're asking about a Biblical topic but we can't do exegesis without a passage!" The second close reason is for when they add a Bible reference but the question still isn't *about* the passage.

But these close reasons could be combined if we could figure out a better way to phrase them. Let me try this as a rough draft:

> Questions about biblical or theological topics are off-topic if they do not primarily concern the interpretation of a specific biblical passage.

Thoughts?

(One advantage of combining these close reasons is that it would free up a close reason for either contemporary application or not-arising-from-the-text questions.)

Comment: I see what you did there and it's well observed! After placing some thought into it, my suggestion is that we could only have one with the following information, `This question isn't about hermeneutical approaches or history / meaning / interpretation of a biblical text.`. What do you think?

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 We don't need to mention all of the exceptions in a close reason - we can trust our users to know that questions about hermeneutical approaches don't get closed with this close reason. And I don't think we should mention it because it would be confusing to people who are new to the site. I also find the "history" of a text part a bit unclear, I've never been too sure what that meant.

Comment: can a new user VTC here? HM... The "history" I presume was used to be broad enough. To me that "history / meaning / interpretation" sounds like exegesis. So it could be substituted to, `This question isn't about hermeneutical approaches or exegesis of a biblical text.`. I like the `hermeneutical approaches` there because that kind of questions aren't as common compared with the exegesis ones...

Comment: No, new users can't VTC, but the problem doesn't just seem to be those who are new to the site - [we do still see closure votes come in from experienced users](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3579/are-questions-about-hermeneutical-approaches-still-on-topic), often due to lack of understanding around H.M. questions.

Answer (score 0):

[curiousdannii points out](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3744/27054) that

> One advantage of combining these close reasons is that it would free
> up a close reason for either contemporary application or
> not-arising-from-the-text questions.

and I had that in mind when producing this answer (which is actually fruit of a discussion in the comments of that previously linked answer).

Initially I thought it could be substituted to

> This question isn't about hermeneutical approaches or history /
> meaning / interpretation of a biblical text.

but curiousdannii didn't like the `hermeneutical approaches` and thought the `history` to be unclear. With that feedback in mind, I've adapted to what o think to be a nice way that would allow us to have only one

> This question isn't about hermeneutical approaches or exegesis of a
> biblical text.

I like the `hermeneutical approaches` there because that kind of questions aren't as common compared with the exegesis ones.