# Criticism of Second Esdras' First Two Chapters

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question, questions, asking-questions

Among the Apocrypha of the [Latin Vulgate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulgate), there is a certain book, called [Second Esdras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2_Esdras), which is found neither in the [Masoretic Text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masoretic_Text), nor in the [Greek Septuagint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Septuagint). Its first two and last two chapters are independent sections, called the *Fifth and Sixth Books of Ezra*, while the middle portion, spanning from the third to the fourteenth chapters, forms what is usually labeled as *Fourth Ezra*.

I would like to post a question about the sources of [the book's first section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flz1l.png), and related textual criticism, but am unsure whether the community might consider it on-topic; and, if not, would anyone have any suggestions on where to post such a question ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's On-Topic as far as I'm concerned.

In the Site Tour we link to [What Texts are Open for Examination?](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/what-texts-are-open-for-examination/6#6).

The community consensus is currently as follows:

> "You build a site for a group of experts. If there are related texts which experts in this field tend to study because the texts are so closely tied to the subject, I would include them as "on topic" for this site." [highest rated answer, by Robert Cartaino](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13/13311)

> "Secondary texts open for direct examination are extrabiblical texts that are helpful in understanding primary texts and/or are commonly referenced/studied by Biblical scholars (examples given below). Also included are translations of primary texts (in English, German, French, Coptic, Latin, etc.), the examination of which is best done using some reference to the primary texts." [second highest rated answer, by Dan](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/687/13311)

I'd align closely with both of these answers, and would definitely like to see more questions covering 2 Esdras and texts of a similar near-biblical scope, which are yet useful for understanding biblical context.